# Focus To Next Item in ListBox in Window Form Application

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

While developing a Windows forms application , I'm having two ListBoxs and a move button.  `ListBox1` contains strings and `ListBox2` is empty.  Whenever I'm pressing the move button, the selected item in `ListBox1` should be moved to `ListBox2`.

I'm getting the default focus on first item on `ListBox1`?  How can I change the focus to the very next element of the element moved to `ListBox2`?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the element that you just moved to listbox2?  It's not very clear.

After moving the item, you could just:

```
listBox2.SelectedIndex = listBox2.Items.Count - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree it is not very clear, anyway if he meant the next element in the ListBox2 it would be null I guess as he just added the item at the end of the ListBox2 items.

But the next element in the ListBox1, would be selected by:

```
private void Move()
    {
        indexOfItemMoved = listBox1.SelectedIndex;

        //move operation

        listBox1.SelectedIndex = indexOfItemMoved; //or indexOfItemMoved+1 / -1 depending on the move operation
    }
```

But remember to check if there is any item at the indexOfItemMoved or you will encounter an exception.